# isset inline validation syntax issues

Tags: php

I am building a form and am currently working through validating the  input.

basically what I want to do is check that they entered something, if so escape it and add it to a variable, otherwise add an error to the potential list of errors to be displayed later.

I currently have:

```
$category = isset($_POST['category']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($DBConnect, $_POST['category']) : $error[] = "Which Category is this request for?";
```

when I do a var_dump on $category (when entered) I get NULL, when not entered I get STRING(35) "Which Category is this request for?"
I have also tried changing the line to read:

```
isset($_POST['category']) ? $category =  mysqli_real_escape_string($DBConnect, $_POST['category']) : $error[] = "Which Category is this request for?";
```

but var_dump still says it is NULL.

Could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

cheers,

Comment: it returns `string(4) "test"`

Comment: Assuming `$_POST['category']` was empty string, it should never become `null` when you perform `mysqli_real_escape_string` .. unless, there's something magic going on that I'm not aware of

Comment: thats why I got a bit confused. not sure what kind of magic was going on. and why I went with isset, because it was returning null.. unless there was some dodgy cached code still hanging around or something that it preferred to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) will only check whether that variable is set or not NULL.

If you want to check for blank also Then please use [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) This will return you the `true` in following cases.

The following things are considered to be empty:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

Comment: wow that was an easy one.
I tried doing it 
`if($_POST['category'] != "") ? mysqli_real_escape_string($DBConnect, $_POST['category']) : $error[] = "Which Category is this request for?";`
but that didnt work... just needed to use empty instead.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

mysql_real_escape_string expects the string to be the first argument and the connection to be the second argument. Try swapping them :)

Update:

Whoops! I read incorrectly and Jack is right, the post spoke of mysqli, not mysql. Sorry.

Comment: This is `mysqli`, not `mysql`